# Ubuntu locked shared files

Tags: samba, chmod, sharing, lock

I have Samba in Ubuntu, where I share one Directory with name "Kurier"
When I paste to this directory new file from other device, I see this file in Ubuntu like Locked. I can unlock this file with command, but how set samba for don't locked new files?

Video example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ry3uLviFPKu_KG04foWuPas-y8tSqNkZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I decided to rewrite this based on your new requirement. The following will work on any vintage of Ubuntu Server, any vintage of Xubuntu, and Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. It will not work on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 because the default umask is not 0002 and there doesn't seem to be any way to fix it.

If you are not running any of the above we can do something else.

This is an example:

[1] Create a folder to be shared:

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/Kurier
```

[2] Change ownership to have group = plugdev:

```
sudo chown :plugdev /srv/Kurier
```

[3] Change permissions such that any new file added locally will "inherit" the group plugdev:

```
sudo chmod 2775 /srv/Kurier
```

[4] Create a samba share definition in /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[Kurier]
path = /srv/Kurier
read only = no
guest ok = yes
force group = plugdev
create mode = 0664
force directory mode = 2775
```

[5] Save the file then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

[6] All local users must be added to the plugdev group to gain read / write access:

```
sudo gpasswd -a username plugdev
```

Any file added from the samba client will save with group = plugdev and permissions of 664. Any file added by a member of the pludev group locally will save with group = plugdev and permissions pf 664

Note: I used the group "plugdev" because it is already available and you as the first user are a member of it.

Also: If you created another share with the name Kurier it should be removed.

Comment: This unlock files only for my account in ubuntu, or files will unlocked (chmod 777) for everybody? I need solution for everybody.

Comment: Samba can force folders/files to have 777/666 permissions. The problem is your local users who add folders/files to that local shared folder will not. You would have to change the default umask on the server and that is problematic. In either event we need more information. Edit your original question and add the output of the following commands: `testparm -s` and `net userhshare info --long`. And what version of Ubuntu are you running. The default umask is different between versions. And is this Ubuntu server or Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Made a typo in the previous comment. Should have been `net usershare info --long`